# I want to upload an image(camera etc...) that has been resized in FileReader of Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, html5-canvas, filereader

I was able to get images from the camera or file explorer.

I was loading to the canvas while resizing the image.

I want to upload this image that has been resized, but the security problem occurs.

```
reader.onload = function (event)
{
    image.onload = function()
    {
        // resize ...
        // canvas handling ...

        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.drawImage(image, x, y, size, size, 0, 0, resize, resize);

        var uri  = canvas.toDataURL();
        var data = uri.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

        $(input_file_selector).val(data);  // << security error
    }

    //...
};
```

file load or camera capture -> paste to canvas and resize -> resized image file upload ...

This process is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the resizing version of `context.drawImage` as you've done--your code should resize the image assuming your drawImage parameters are valid).

But...The security error are likely a result of attempting to draw a cross-domain image onto canvas.

Cross-domain draws will taint the canvas and prevent `canvas.toDataURL` from occurring. You can upload a cross-domain image if it's headers allow anonymous access and you also specify in javascript that the image allows anonymous access.  You can read about enabling cross-domain transfers here: http://enable-cors.org/

Here is an example using FileReader to let the user drag an image into a dropzone.  The image will be scaled 2X and added as a new image on the webpage.

```js
// dropzone event handlers
var dropzone;
dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");
dropzone.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropzone.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

//
function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}
//

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

//
function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  handleFiles(files);
}

//
function handleFiles(files) {

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    // get the next file that the user selected
    var file = files[i];
    var imageType = /image.*/;

    // don't try to process non-images
    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
      continue;
    }

    // a seed img element for the FileReader
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = file;

    // get an image file from the user
    // this uses drag/drop, but you could substitute file-browsing
    var reader=new FileReader();
    reader.onload=(function(aImg){
      return function(e) {
        aImg.onload=function(){

          // draw the aImg onto the canvas
          var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
          var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
          canvas.width=aImg.width*2;
          canvas.height=aImg.height*2;
          ctx.drawImage(aImg,0,0,aImg.width,aImg.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

          // make the jpeg image
          var newImg=new Image();
          newImg.onload=function(){
            newImg.id="newest";
            document.body.appendChild(newImg);
          }
          newImg.src=canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        }
        // e.target.result is a dataURL for the image
        aImg.src = e.target.result;
      }; 
    })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  } // end for

} // end handleFiles
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
#dropzone{border:1px solid blue; width:300px;height:300px;}
```

```html
<h4>Drag an image from desktop to blue dropzone.</h4>
<div id="dropzone"></div>
<div id="preview"></div>
```